# Problemas al actualizar campo de base de datos con contenteditable, ajax y php

Tags: php, html5, ajax, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando modificar un th (el de estado) de una tabla, cuyo valor se ha obtenido consultando a la base de datos, mediante el atributo de html5 `contenteditable`, `ajax` y `phpcontenteditable` , pero no hay manera. Creo que la cosa está en que no redirige al archivo donde se hace el update porque el th lo puedo editar, el jquery coge bien los valores en las variables, pero después el valor no se actualiza (y no aparece el "echo" con "estoy aquí" puesto de prueba), aunque puede que me equivoque y sea otra cosa.

Dejo por aquí todo el código que tengo por si me podéis ayudar.

verpedidos.php (archivo donde se encuentra la tabla con el campo a modificar y el script con ajax)

```html
<thead>
  <tr data-row-id="<?php echo $pedidos['npedido'];?>">
     <th colspan="1" class="tcabecera">Pedido nº: <?php echo $pedidos['npedido']; ?></th>
     <th colspan="3" class="tcabecera">Matrícula: <?php echo $pedidos['nmatricula']; ?></th>   
     <th colspan="1" class="tcabecera">Estado: </th>
     <th colspan="3" class="tcabecera editable-col" contenteditable="true" oldVal ="<?php echo 
     $pedidos['estado'];?>"><?php echo $pedidos['estado']; ?></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('th.editable-col').on('focusout', function() {
     var estado = $(this).text();
     var id = $(this).parent('tr').attr('data-row-id');
     var oldVal = $(this).attr('oldVal');
     /*if(oldVal === estado)
     return false;*/
                                
     $.ajax({   
       type: 'post',  
       url: 'editarPedidos2.php',  
       data: 'estado=' +estado+ '&id=' +id+ '&oldVal=' +oldVal
     });
   });
});

</script>
```

editarPedidos2.php (donde se hace la actualización)

```php
if(isset($_POST)){
  $estado = $_POST['estado'];
  echo("estoy aqui");
  $estado = ucfirst($estado);
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $oldVal = $_POST['oldVal'];
   
  if($oldVal=='Pedido') {
     $sql = "UPDATE pedidos SET estado='".$estado."' WHERE npedido='".$id."'";
                    
     if(mysql_query($sql)){
       echo "<p>Actualizado.</p>";
     } else {
       echo "<p>Error</p>";
     }
  }
}
```

Millones de gracias.

PD. es la primera vez que escribo en el foro y no sé si he puesto bien el código y/o las etiquetas, lo siento.